# Warning: Illegal string offset 'tag'

Tags: tags, warnings

I am getting this warning on the below line, any help?

```
<label class="inputLabel"<?php echo ($field['tag']) ? ' for="'.$field['field']['tag'].'"': ''; ?>><?php echo $field['title']; ?></label>      **strong text**
```

Below is the section of the code.

```
<div class="discountForm<?php echo $selectionStyle; ?> discount<?php echo $box; ?>">
<fieldset class="discount">
  <legend><?php echo $selection[$i]['module']; ?></legend>
  <?php echo $selection[$i]['redeem_instructions']; ?>
  <div class="gvBal larger"><?php echo $selection[$i]['checkbox']; ?></div>
  <div class="gvBal">
  <?php foreach ($selection[$i]['fields'] as $field) { ?>
    <label class="inputLabel"<?php echo ($field['tag']) ? ' for="'.$field['field']['tag'].'"': ''; ?>><?php echo $field['title']; ?></label>      
    <?php echo $field['field']; ?> 
  <?php } ?>
  <?php   if ( ($selection[$i]['module'] != MODULE_ORDER_TOTAL_INSURANCE_TITLE) && ($selection[$i]['module'] != MODULE_ORDER_TOTAL_SC_TITLE) ) { ?>
    <div class="buttonRow"><?php echo zen_image(zen_output_string($template->get_template_dir(BUTTON_IMAGE_UPDATE, DIR_WS_TEMPLATE, $current_page_base, 'buttons/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '/') . BUTTON_IMAGE_UPDATE), BUTTON_UPDATE_ALT, '', '', 'onclick="updateForm();"'); ?></div>
  <?php   } ?>
  </div> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How is `$field` variable composed? Please provide the code.

Comment: Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a `string` using an index that is a `string`.

You are treating `$field` as an array while it is actually a `string`. Check your code and what is the `$selection[$i]['fields']` output.

Comment: this warning started to show up after I upgraded to PHP 5.6 from 5.3, something happened between the two versions.